# Can I serve files stored in Google Cloud Storage via a http.FileServer in golang?

Tags: go, google-cloud-storage

I have developed a small web application that runs a web server in golang.
Each user can login, view the list of their docs (previously uploaded) and click on an item to view an html page that shows some fields of the document plus an  tag with a src attribute

The src attribute includes an url like "mydocuments/download/123-456-789.pdf"

On the server side I handle the URL ("mydocuments/download/*") via an http Handler

```
mymux.HandleFunc(pat.Get("/mydocuments/download/:docname"), DocDownloadHandler)
```

where:

1. I check that the user has the rights to view the document in the url
2. Then I create a fileserver that obviously re-maps the url to the real path of the folder where the files are stored on the filesystem of the server

```
fileServer := http.StripPrefix("/mydocs/download/",http.FileServer(http.Dir("/the-real-path-to-documents-folder/user-specific-folder/)))
```

and of course I serve the files

```
fileServer.ServeHTTP(w, r)
```

IMPORTANT: the directory where the documents are stored is not the static-files directory I sue for the website but a directory where all files end after being uploaded by users.

**My QUESTION**
As I am trying to convert the code for it to work **also** on Google Cloud, I am trying to change the code so that files are stored in a bucket (or, better in "sub-directories" -as they do not properly exist- of a bucket).

How can I modify the code so to map the real document url as available via the cloud storage bucket?
Can I still use the http.FileServer technique above (if so what should I use instead of http.Dir to map the bucket "sub-folder" path where the documents are stored)?

I hope I was enough clear to explain my issue...
I apologise in advance for any unclear point...

Comment: Some options: Give the user direct access to the resource using a signed URL, write code to proxy the request to GCS, use [http.FS](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#FS) with an [fs.FS](https://pkg.go.dev/io/fs#FS) backed by GCS.  It's possible that a fs.FS for GCS already exists, but you may need to write one.

Comment: [http.FileSystem](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#FileSystem) is an interface. You can implement it however you like.

Comment: Wow, really interesting. I was not aware of the latest fs.FS introduced in version 1.16. 
That should be the right path to follow... although I will need to study it "a bit" more... :)

In the meantime I suppose that I can use the http.ServeFile function to still serve each single file via the application (and for the time being I am not going to use the fileServer as I had in mind...

Who knows, maybe somebody is going to create a FS backed by the GCS in order to write "agnostic" code to replicate that behaviour.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Some options are:

1. Give the user direct access to the resource using a signed URL.
   Write code to proxy the request to GCS.
   Use [http.FS](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#FS) with an [fs.FS](https://pkg.go.dev/io/fs#FS) backed by GCS.

It's possible that a fs.FS for GCS already exists, but you may need to write one.

2. You can use [http.FileSystem](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#FileSystem) since it is an interface and can be implemented however you like.